# Replacing document.write with a non-replacing InnerHTML

Tags: javascript, dom, innerhtml, appendchild, document.write

I am currently web scraping information by using import.io. I am scraping from weather sites to show the margin of inconsistencies across a single zip code for a statistics project.

```
document.write("<i>" + k + "</i>" + "<p>" + d.data[k] + "</p>");
```

My problem is that this document.write erases all of my page content and replaces it with pure json data. I tried using innerHTML, but I only get the last data result from the crawler.

Is there some way of implementing an appendChild or InnerHTML that wouldn't write over the previously written data?

Referenced:
http://import.io/data/integrate/#js

Comment: `document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<i>" + k + "</i><p>" + data[k] + "</p>")`

Comment: or `document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("i")).textContent = k; document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("p")).textContent = data[k];`

Comment: Thanks that worked. Thanks again Cookie Monster... you're a genius. I feel terrible getting stumped on problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML
  ("beforeend", 
   "<i>" + k + "</i><p>" + data[k] + "</p>"
  )
```

or

```
document.body.appendChild
  (
  document.createElement("i")
  ).textContent = k; 

document.body.appendChild
  (
  document.createElement("p")
  ).textContent = data[k];
```